# Запись в конец файла c++

Tags: c++, файлы, запись

Здравствуйте, я сделал запись в файл с одного класса, но нужно дописать в этот же файл результаты из второго класса, результаты накладываются и в итоге в файле только результаты работы второго класса. Как сделать запись в конец файла? 
Мы используем ios_base::app????
Спасибо Brave_Lime за ответ.

```
 std::ofstream vmdelet_out;     //создаем поток 
 vmdelet_out.open("file.txt", std::ios::app);  // открываем файл для записи 
 в конец
 vmdelet_out << "Exit"; // сама запись
 vmdelet_out.close();   // закрываем файл
```

Comment: покажите код всего этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Запись

```
std::ofstream vmdelet_out;                    //создаем поток 
vmdelet_out.open("file.txt", std::ios::app);  // открываем файл для записи в конец
vmdelet_out << "Exit";                        // сама запись
vmdelet_out.close();                          // закрываем файл
```

---

### Построчное чтение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::fstream f;                     // создаем поток
    f.open("file.txt", std::ios::in);   // открываем файл для чтения
    if (f)                              // если файл открылся
    {
        std::string buf;                // создаем буфер, куда будет считываться информация
        while (getline(f, buf))         //  Пока мы получили строку - тело цикла исполняется ||  когда файл закончился (все строки считались) - цикл false
        {
             std::cout << buf;          // выводит последнюю прочитанную строку
             //... остальные ваши действия     
        }
    }
}
```

*Надеюсь помог!*

Comment: Да, может еще подскажите. Когда я считываю из концевого файла в массив структур и вывожу на экран элементы этой структуры, то ничего выводиться.

Comment: @HiHello Думаю, стоит открыть новый вопрос, про считывание из файла и **приложить код**  :)