# Как дозаписать данные в файл ".txt" в C++?

Tags: c++, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу программу на языке C++. В ходе реализации приходится открывать одни и те же файлы в разных функциях, но при новом открытии старые данные стираются и записываются только новые. Нагромождать одну функцию не хочется, при этом выводить весь результат в конце тоже довольно не просто, заполнение файла идет по ходу выполнения программы. Как можно сохранить старые данные и продолжить заполнение? Спасибо))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов: [Запись в конец файла c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663513/); [Как сохранять данные в файле txt C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962381/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте флаги для открытия.

```
// app - All output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its existing contents.

std::ofstream oFile("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt", std::ios::app);
```